# Could an ecosystem entirely made up of parasites be possible?

Tags: science-based, biology, environment, parasites

One of the settings for a story I'm writing is gigantic worm-like animal. Being so large it stands to reason that there would be comparatively smaller animals living within and on the surface of it. Would it then be possible for these smaller animals to also have even smaller animals living on and in them, going all the way down like a russian nesting doll set of parasites?

EDIT: I didn't include it in my original question because I wanted the answers to be as rooted in biology as possible, but the giant worm in this scenario subsists by devouring other alternate universes/realities. The creatures living within and on it range from the same variety of eaters of "intangible substance" as it is, and others that eat flesh and blood in the same way animals in our reality do - along the way this intangible food source is gradually turned into something these other creatures can feed upon. So as admittedly ridiculous as it sounds, this ecosystem does have an input source of energy.

Comment: So, is the worm also a parasite, and there are no other animals except parasites (as per the title)?

Comment: All parasites, including the giant worm. Let's just pretend for the sake of argument that it is as high as the food web goes or else we'd have an endless chain of parasites going up as well as down.

Comment: I mean, animals feed on plants, so if you're extremely loose with the definition to the point of being basically incorrect, than yes. On a better point, the energy has to come from somewhere, so gut response, entirely, no, mostly, yes.

Comment: Short answer, no, longer answer, still no .. this is the same as previous questions asked here about could a population survive by cannibalism and the answer is no, what you have is a closed ecosystem with no other nutrient source but itself, the same as a single animal cannibalising it's own cells as it starves, eventually it dies .. that's the answer for the headline question, a further comment is that's not at all what you have described in the body-text, the giant worm they live on presumably eats something other than them so the ecosystem is not *"entirely made up of parasites"* is it.

Comment: @Pelinore If we were to consider the sun as alive, would the creatures (plants) that eat it's 'waste' (light) be considered parasites?

Comment: @Zautech are organisms that live of the discarded organic matter of plants (leaf mold etc) parasites? so how about organisms that live off dung or other discarded material from other animals? .. you answered your own question when you said 'waste'

Comment: "russian nesting doll set" you mean Matrioshka doll.

Comment: ...tick>>>monkey>>>tick>>>monkey>>>tick...

Comment: This is the theory of hyperparasitism. Yes, you have Russian nesting dolls of parasites in real life, I think the largest I've heard of goes all the way to 5 levels.

Answer (score 7):

As some comments note, it is impossible for an ecosystem to be *entirely* parasitic. Somehow, somewhere, there has to be input to the system - on Earth, that's in the form of stuff like phytoplankton which pretty much consumes the unmatched power of the Sun.

That being said, if the worm ate plants that harvested sunlight like regular plants on Earth, then it *might* be possible for such an ecosystem to exist - if the worm eats far more food than it needs, then the parasites that live on it would sort of keep it "under control" and not growing too much, and those parasites would be kept in check in turn by their parasites, and so on and so forth. Very, *very* unlikely, but if the worm is allowed to eat the sun, there's a little less suspension of disbelief there.

Answer (score 5):

> So nat'ralists observe, a flea
> Hath smaller fleas that on him prey;
> And these have smaller fleas to bite 'em.
> And so proceeds ad infinitum.

-Jonathan Swift

What you're thinking of is called [hyperparasitism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparasite), and it's absolutely a thing that exists, although perhaps not to the degree that you're planning for your story.  From an evolutionary perspective it's a bit odd that all species would choose parasitism over mutualism or predation, but just because it's unlikely doesn't mean it's impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it has an energy and matter input, it doesn't have to be a biological one. So the original creature gets it's energy and excess from non biological sources, then all the parasites after that can exist.

Answer (score 1):

There cannot be *perpetuum mobile*. It must be some source of the energy in the system.

The possible solutions are:

- The worm consumes something that can be used to extract the energy out of it. Even inside a human, there are more microbial cells in the intestines than human cells in all body, and microbial cells feed on cellulose and other food components human cannot digest. Then human digests these micro-organisms, they are important source of some vitamins.
- The worm exists for the limited time. Some insects are known not to eat in the adult stage, they have enough resources from the previous stages of development and do not live for very long.
- New symbionts are constantly coming into the worm from outside, and finally get consumed but may not be immediately and not always. Some highlander species of spiders only eat one another, but the population still holds because it is supplemented by migrant spiders arriving to such an unfavorable ecosystem.

And, obviously, the chain of usual biological parasites must end somewhere. Anything based on regular biochemistry cannot be smaller than an atom of hydrogen, and likely should be much larger. I am not sure about something more exotic, as all elementary particles in the Standard Model are considered point-like and without spatial size, even if their masses vary (with neutrinos being among the lightest).